# Правильно говорити "адреса" чи "адрес"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова

Помітила, що є два варіанти вживання. Тож як правильно, "мій адрес" чи "моя адреса"?

Comment: пошук в мережі на *адрес чи дареса* видав багато достойних відповідей, чим вони вас не влаштували?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сайт [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/adresa-j-adres)
[image]

У СУМ online (1-8 томи)

> **[АДРЕ́СА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=519&page=22)** **1**. Позначення місця проживання чи перебування кого-небудь або місцезнаходження чого-небудь; **2**. інформ.
>   Унікальний ідентифікатор або номер, що присвоюється комп'ютерному
>   пристрою чи об’єкту комп'ютерної мережі для операцій із ними.
>
> **[А́ДРЕС](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=518&page=22)** Письмове вітання з нагоди відзначення ювілею чи іншої видатної події.

***Правильно "моя адреса"***